# Display list selected value on label

Tags: java, label, awt, selectedvalue

ItemListener is implemented here, below code is just the part. Here, i need the selected item from the list to be displayed on the label. This code isn't working. 
Thankyou for helping.

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
{
    String data = objectOfList.getSelectedItem();
    objectOfLabel.setText("selected item: " + data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add an item listener to the combobox whose itemStateChanged() method gets called each time the user selects or deselects an item.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html#itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent)

I've written a small demo you can use as a reference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
    comboBox.addItem("item1");
    comboBox.addItem("item2");

    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            label.setText("selected item: " + comboBox.getSelectedItem());
        }
    });

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(comboBox);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: The example and the document helped. Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because the Event Dispatch Thread(Java GUI thread) is busy executing code inside `actionPerformed()` method. So, you can put the code inside a
 thread in `actionPerformed()` method, then the label will be updated.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String data = objectOfList.getSelectedItem();
            objectOfLabel.setText("selected item: " + data);
        }     
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: That's working just once. The first element I select gets on the label. But if the selection is changed, the value isn't updatable.